# Basic jQuery In browser Developer Tools not working

Tags: jquery

In both IE and Chrome for the past couple weeks, basic selectors and common functions are not working through my developer tools.  Has anyone else had this problem and/or know what's going on?

`$(".class").css("display","none");`

Something like this doesn't work in my Dev Tools anymore and it previously did.

Comment: Sounds like the page you are on lost it's jQuery reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when I stumble on to a Minimal Download Strategy (MDS) page, I used to navigate back to a different page to get a jQuery reference back, but lately I've just started pasting this into my browser dev tools console:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

And then you should get some jQuery back -- modify it to use some other CDN if you want obviously.

Comment: This worked.  I thought all the pages I was working with had a reference loaded.. I was wrong. Thanks!